# javascript Scope issue in Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope, extjs4

I have this class which automatically generates JSON stores from server. Stores are created on the fly and are viewable in Firebug's DOM.
I think i have some scope issues.When i want to console.log(Ext.getStore('AdminSettings')) (which AdminSettings is one of the created stores) inside Ext.Ajax.request`s callback function, 'AdminSettings' store is returned but if i put console.log(Ext.getStore('AdminSettings')) everywhere outside callback function,i get undefined message in firebug and my store is not instantiated.
See code comments to see it in action.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : './account/getadminstores',
callback : function(options, success, response) {
var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
var adminStores = new Array();
// setup and intitialize on the fly stores
for ( var key1 in json) {
var storeFields = new Array();
for ( var key2 in json[key1]) {// if (i==1){break;}
for ( var key3 in json[key1][key2]) {
storeFields.push(key3);}
break;};
Ext.define('MA.store.' + key1, {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
fields : storeFields,
storeId : key1,
data : json[key1]
});
Ext.create('MA.store.'+key1);};
console.log(Ext.getStore('AdminSettings'));
//returns MA.store.AdminSettings in firebug and everything is fine 
                }
            });//eof Ext.Ajax.request
            console.log(Ext.getStore('AdminSettings'));
//returns undefined which is strange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.Ajax.request is asynchronous. Your final console.log call returns nothing because at the time it is executed the request has not yet completed. Any code depending on the results of the request's callback will need to be executed by the callback as well.

Comment: i got you on asynchronous thing.would you please provide a solution?should i use synchronous call?does such thing exist?i have a viewport and a grid in it and i will need the stores as soon as page loads if not the grid`s store will be undefined.

Comment: Wrap the initialization code for your grid in a function which can be called from Ext.Ajax.request's callback. You may need to use a card layout or the like as a placeholder until the grid is ready. That said, if your page is so dependent on the results of the request then you are probably better off delivering the data to the client as part of the page itself so that it is available for use immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of javascript, `callback` doesn't get called until after the ajax request finishes, so the Ext data store doesn't get defined either.

The order of execution of your script is:

1. Ajax request is initialized
2. console.log is executed (undefined since the datastore hasn't been defined yet)
3. javascript is waiting for an ajax response from ./account/getadminstores
4. response comes in, callback function is called (which defines the data store)

Comment: any solutions on how can i suspend rendering widgets until ajax request is completed?